# Trying to export a react native stack navigation

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

i am trying to export a react native stack navigation but i am getting an error

*Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

*ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

Check the render method of 'TopsCloset'.

Stack navigation - File a

```
function TopsScreen ({navigation}) {
    return(
        <View>
    <TouchableOpacity 
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TopsScreen')} 
>
<Image 
style= {liststyles2.listitems} 
source={require('./images/tops.png')} 
/>
</TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={liststyles2.listtext}>Tops</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export {TopsScreen}

function TopsScreenCont ({navigation}) {
    return(
        <View>
        <Text style={liststyles2.listtext}>Tops</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export {TopsScreenCont}

  const TopsNavStack = createStackNavigator();

function TopsScreenNav() {
  return (
    <TopsNavStack.Navigator>
      <TopsNavStack.Screen name="TopsScreen" component={TopsScreen} />
      <TopsNavStack.Screen name="TopsScreenCont" component={TopsScreenCont} />
    </TopsNavStack.Navigator>
  );
}
export {TopsScreenNav}

function TopsScreenExport() {
    return(
    <NavigationContainer independent = {true}>
    <TopsNavStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
    }

export default TopsScreenExport();
```

Trying to import TopsScreenExport both with and without {}.

FIle b - trying to import the stack

```
import TopsScreenExport from './Tops'

const TopsCloset = () => {
    return (
    <View> 
    <TopsScreenExport />
    </View>
    );
}
```

I am trying to create just a simple stack navigation to work  with touchable opacity. Note on the App file the i already call a bottomtabsnavigator which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well problem solved.

What i had wrong was the export default, indeed , and i had to import the second component

```
export function TopsScreenExport() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <TopsNavStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And

```
export function TopsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TopsScreen')}>
        <Image style={liststyles2.listitems} source={require('./images/tops.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={liststyles2.listtext}>Tops</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And on the Myitems.js

```
import { TopsScreenExport, TopsScreen } from 'Tops.js'
```